# Change background color of the inside of characters in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, colors

I've encountered a problem for which I couldn't find a solution. I'm fairly new to WPF.

What I want to do is to change the background color certain characters in a textblock, but only of the "inside" of the character.

For example: I have this textblock:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    Contenido
</TextBlock>
```

And I'd like to have the inside of the characters "o", "e" and "d" to be of a different color. I wouldn't mind having to put those letters in a subsequent textblock, but so far what I achieved is this:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="36" FontFamily="Arial">
    C
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock FontSize="36" FontFamily="Arial" Background="Red" >
    o
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock FontSize="36" FontFamily="Arial">
    nt
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock FontSize="36" FontFamily="Arial" Background="Red" >
    e
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock FontSize="36" FontFamily="Arial">
    ni
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock FontSize="36" FontFamily="Arial" Background="Red" >
    d
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock FontSize="36" FontFamily="Arial" Background="Red" >
    o
</TextBlock>
```

But of course that renders the whole background of the textblock in red, not only the inside of the letter.

I know I could do it as an image but I think of it as an interesting challenge.

Comment: This can't be achieved out of the box. What is the end goal? Are you trying to design some sort of logo? If that's the case, I would suggest creating something in Photoshop or Paint and then simply importing it as an image.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it's for a logo. I thought it could be done in wpf so that it scaled properly in different screen sizes and resolutions. I have no experience in Photoshop, I guess it would have to be done in .svg for that requirement.

Comment: Anyone care to tell me the reason for the downvote? I don't think the question violates any rule of SO (or SE for that matter).